# Multi-part identifier could not be bound, without join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone point out the problem with the below query, I keep getting the following error: "Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The multi-part identifier could not be bound."

```
select top 1 * 
from [ADatabase].[dbo].[Tracking] 
where [ADatabase].[dbo].[Drivers].[DriverId] = [ADatabase].[dbo].[Tracking].[DriverOneId] 
and [UTCEventTime] > '2019-02-27' 
order by [Id] desc
```

I have looked at several examples of this issue but they all seem to be linked to more complex multi table join queries.

Thanks

Comment: Tricky to tell - answers are saying you need join - but it may be that you were trying to do an *existence* check instead - what was your *intention* behind the `[ADatabase].[dbo].[Drivers].[DriverId] = [ADatabase].[dbo].[Tracking].[DriverOneId]` predicate?

Comment: You can't use a table that doesn't appear in a `FROM` clause. Why is `Drivers` there? What are you trying to do? Return all matching rows from both tables? Or only `Tracking` fields that have a matching driver?

Answer (score 2):

You apparently need some sort of `JOIN` . . . And table aliases!

```
select top 1 t.*
from [ADatabase].[dbo].[Tracking] t join
     [ADatabase].[dbo].[Drivers] d
     on d.[DriverId] = t.[DriverOneId] and
        t.[UTCEventTime] > '2019-02-27'
order by t.[Id] desc;
```

You can only refer to tables and columns in tables that are in a `FROM` clause.  You can't just add a four-part identifier in a `WHERE` or `SELECT` (or elsewhere) and expect SQL to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Error message clearly says you need `JOIN` :

```
SELECT TOP (1) T.*, D.*
from [ADatabase].[dbo].[Tracking] T INNER JOIN
     [ADatabase].[dbo].[Drivers] D
     ON D.[DriverId] = T.[DriverId]
WHERE T.[UTCEventTime] > '2019-02-27' -- DON'T KNOW ABOUT TABLE WHERE IT COMES FROM
ORDER BY T.[Id] desc; -- DON'T KNOW ABOUT TABLE WHERE IT COMES FROM
```

Comment: No - the error message says nothing about a join. A join **might** be the most appropriate fix for this, but let's not mislead the poster about how to interpret or diagnose the problem. And now that you have joined, the query logic probably needs to be adjusted to account for the <unknown> relationship between the tables - specifically the order by clause.

Comment: @SMor. .  I have seen `multi-part identifier could not be bound`. which means something you have but you didn't include that things.

Comment: @SMor. . . And of-course my first line might miss lead the OP. But for the code that provided it is enough to clarify what the issue was.